# rails active record find record from inherited table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a table called Company < ApplicationRecord and Company::A < Company, Company::B < Company, Company::C < Company.

How can I query all the companies like Company.all rather than queuing Company::A.all + Company::B.all

Please note I don't have company table in DB its a model and not using STI

Comment: You don't have a Companies table but your Company model inherits from ApplicationRecord? Can you explain why please?

Comment: Can you update your question to include your actual model definitions?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, because when you call `all`, you are actually querying `find(:all)` from database. It will create a query to fetch records from tables which has the corresponding name to your model ( in this case you need table `companies` ). However, you don't have that `companies` table, you won't be able to make that query.

The only way I can think about is to define a method to your `Company` class

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  def self.all
    return Company::A.all + Company::B.all
  end
end
```